# [Error]: Type info TC,N,D not yet supported

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

```
class ABC{
   @NSManaged var liked: Bool
   .....
 }
```

in other class

```
class xyz{
 func afunc(){
 let item = ABC()
   if item.liked == true{ // getting crash on this line
}}}
```

> [Error]: Type info TC,N,D not yet supported
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[...]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d78310'
>   *** First throw call stack:

I am simply accessing a value that I have created in a class and
its working fine on one device(ios version 8.1 and 8.3) and throwing error on another device(ios version 8.4).

Comment: its just  -->   item.liked == true { }

Comment: so there is no item, oder no property "liked". Show some more code.

Comment: can you show some code ?

Comment: From the code you're showing here, liked is never set? Therefore it will be nil and cause your crash

Comment: I think this code does not compile. You are writing an IF directly in the class. It should be inside a `func` or a `computed property` instead.

Comment: @Swinny89 its NSManaged var we can not set initial value to it. And if I am sending its value from backend then also its showing same error and its working fine before ios 8.4 version.

Comment: @ appzYourLife you are right I just edited my code thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have created `swift class`. Then it should be like below :

```
class ABC {

    var liked = Bool()

}

class XYZ {

    func execute() {

        let item = ABC()
        if item.liked == true { // getting crash on this line
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class ClassA: NSObject {
    var liked:Bool

    override init() {
      liked = true
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       execute();
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func execute(){
        let item = ClassA();
        if item.liked==true{
           print(item.liked)
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: i write this programm as xcode project and also working. if you want i can also mail you that copy.

Comment: I  used NSManaged var in my model class that can not be initialize like this. Have you ever faced any error like **[Error]: Type info TC,N,D not yet supported**

Comment: While which exception you displayed in question its only when we try to call such selectors which are not available for those class object. To save from exception you can check object for those selector by using "RespondToSelector" before call.